# NetBeans y Proyectos Java Web

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Realice la instalación del IDE 8.2 de NetBeans y posteriormente baje Tomcat 9 para Windows 10 y se ha configurado su arranque desde el IDE.  Posteriormente procedo a la creción de un proyecto Web Java

1.-
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.-
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.-
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.-
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo hasta aquí sin problema.  Y luego lo único que hago es ejecutar el programa con lo que el mismo IDE crea automáticamente y se borra  el proyecto por completo y sale el siguiente mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El proyecto desaparece del árbol de proyectos y no tengo idea de que pasa si no he creado ni un solo objeto o ingresado código al proyecto.  Se puede explicar de alguna manera que pasa... Gracias.

Comment: ¿Has tratado de limpiar y volver a arrancar el proyecto?

Comment: Gracias Fernando, pero te cuento que si he hecho de todo y he rehecho el proyecto base y vuelvo y complio y se borra!!!

Comment: ¿Ya leíste el log?  El problema ocurre en el context.xml

Comment: Existen muchas posibilidades, habria que ver cual es la configuración del Tomcat que te descargaste. POr lo cual te recomiendo que utilices el bundle que viene con el Netbeans a ver si tienes el mismo problema. Por otro lado, también te recomiendo bajar el tomcat, limpiar la carpeta work, subir el tomcat, hacer un Clean and Build y finalmente un Run, ojo NO debug como muestra la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Encontre el error y era que no estaba el proyecto dentro de otra carpeta fuera de la instalación en donde si pueda sobrescribir el mismo para su publicación!!!

Comment: Nunca es tarde, así sea 3 meses después de haber realizado la pregunta.